# Is this mathematically unambiguous. If not, what notation and vocabulary should I use? Left/right map inverses.

Tags: soft-question, notation, category-theory, formal-languages, article-writing

The condition is:

> ... given two maps $f: A\to B,$  and $g :B \to A$, there exists no map $h : B \to A$ such that $h$ is surjective and $f = h g h^{-1}$, or $h$ is injective and $f = h^{-1} g h$ ?

Specifically all objects $A,B$ are kleene star closures of differing finite alphabets: $A = \Sigma^*$, $A = \Sigma'^*$ and all maps $f, g, h$ are string homomorphisms.

I like the "-1" notation. Should I add "for some left/right inverse $h^{-1}$"?

Comment: I believe the notation $h^{-1}$ is usually only used when $h$ is invertible. The notation suggests it's uniquely determined by $h$. btw in the expressions $f=hgh^{-1}$ and $f=h^{-1}gh$ the domains and codomains don't seem to match up correctly (eg $h$ has codomain $A$ but $f$ has codomain $B$).

Comment: @stewbasic you forgot to mention what notation I should use.  Thanks

Comment: I was going to suggest something like "there exist no maps $h:B\to A$, $k:A\to B$ such that $hk=\mathrm{id}_A$ and $f=hgk$" (but wanted to clarify the domains and codomains first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $(-)^{-1}$ unequivocally means "inverse" in this context, i.e. a morphism such that $h \circ h^{-1} = \operatorname{id}$ *and* $h^{-1} \circ h = \operatorname{id}$ (when it exists, and when it does it is unique). It is not reasonable to use that notation for a mere left/right inverse.

Even if you clarify that $h^{-1}$ is just a left/right inverse (and if you absolutely want to use that notation you definitely should), people will get confused. If I read the passage you wrote, it wouldn't even cross my mind to check what $h^{-1}$ means, since this is such a standard notation; but then I would wonder why $h$ is invertible. The previous scenario is not a hypothetical: this is exactly what happened when I read your question...

Another point to consider: you use the same notation ($h^{-1}$) for two different things (left inverse and right inverse) in the same sentence. Using the same notation for two different things in the same text is already a big no-no, but in the same sentence it's particularly egregious.

Remember that you write math for others too, and if a notation is likely to confuse everyone I would just drop it and find a new one. In your case, I would just choose a letter for the right inverse and write something like:

> ... given two maps $f: A\to B,$  and $g :B \to A$, there neither exists a **surjective** map $h : B \to A$ **with right inverse $k$** such that $f = h g k$, nor any **injective** map $h$ **with left inverse $l$** such that $f = l g h$ ?

Another name for "right inverse" is "section", so if you want to emphasize that it's a right inverse you can call it $s$. And another name for left inverse is "retraction" so you can call it $r$. But I would never call either $h^{-1}$.